# Tailing a local file using fileevent

Tags: file, events, tcl, readable

I am trying to tail a file using `fileevent` (Should only Tcl 8.4 version, so I can't use `chan` command).

```
% proc GetData {chan} {
 set data [read $chan]
    puts "[string length $data] $data"
    if {[eof $chan]} {
        fileevent $chan readable {}
    }
}
% 
% 
% 
%  set fp [open "|tail -f /home/dinesh/input" r+]
file7
% fconfigure $fp
-blocking 1 -buffering full -buffersize 4096 -encoding utf-8 -eofchar {{} {}} -translation {auto lf}
% fconfigure $fp -blocking 0  -buffering  line 
% 
% 
% 
% 
%  fileevent $fp readable [list GetData $fp]
%
```

I have changed the file contents using `cat` command in another terminal, but still `GetData` is not getting called.

With `gets $fp line`, I am able to get the modified contents, but why fileevent is not triggered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks scheduled with `fileevent` only occur when you are running the event loop, and `tclsh` doesn't run an event loop for you by default. Try doing this to see if my hypothesis is correct:

```
update
```

If it is, you'll need to design your program to work driven by callbacks. The standard way of running the event loop is this:

```
vwait forever
# Any global variable name would do, but “forever” has a nice feel
```

But that's a bit less helpful for your interactive testing. (One way round this is to load the Tk package; that turns on running the event loop by default so you don't need to do so explicitly. And gives you windows to manage, so it isn't without consequences…)